# Custom Field PropertySchema Type=User

Tags: development, custom-field-types, spfield, spfielduser

I have a custom field in my SP Project.  In my .xml file, I have a propertySchema and a user field inside it.  Currently the field does not accept multiple users/groups.  How can I change that?

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
<PropertySchema>
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="AlertUsers" DisplayName="Alter the following users: " Type="User" AllowMultipleValues="true" AllowMultiple="true">
    </Field>
  </Fields>
</PropertySchema>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but thought I'd answer for completeness anyway.

For multiple users you should have:
Type=”MultiUser”
Multi-"True"

Comment: I think it actually is Mult="True" (without the i)?

Comment: I think you are right,